# JavaScript: If argument is defined, function searches for index of where the argument appears in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, search, indexing

I tried to solve the problem below with JS:

> Define a function, myLastIndexOf, that accepts up to three arguments:
>
> - array
> - searchValue
> - startIdx (optional)
>
> 1. myLastIndexOf should return the last index at which the searchValue appears in the array.
> 2. If the searchValue isn't in the array, myLastIndexOf should return -1.
> 3. If startIdx is defined, myLastIndexOf should start looking for the seachValue at that index, and then move toward the front of the array as it looks for the value.

Here is my code:

```js
function myLastIndexOf (array, searchValue, startIdx){
  if (startIdx !== undefined){
    for (i=startIdx; i>=0; i--){
      //console.log(array[i])
      if (array[i] === searchValue){
        return i
      }
    }
  }
  else if (startIdx === undefined){
    for (i=0; i<array.length; i++){
      console.log(array[i])
      if (array[i] === searchValue){
        return i
      }
    }
  }

}

console.log(myLastIndexOf(['gee', 'gee', 'gee', 'gee', 'baby', 'baby'], 'gee')); // => 3
```

The code should return 3 but instead I get zero.  What do I have wrong in my code?

Comment: You're returning on first match itself

Comment: That code doesn't return 1, it returns 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is starting from `i=0` it should start from `i = array.length -1`. And `i` should decrease instead of increasing.

```js
function myLastIndexOf (array, searchValue, startIdx){

  if (startIdx !== undefined){

    for (let i=startIdx; i>=0; i--){

      //console.log(array[i])

      if (array[i] === searchValue){
        return i
      }
    }
  }

  else if (startIdx === undefined){

    for (let i=array.length - 1; i>=0; i--){

      console.log(array[i])

      if (array[i] === searchValue){
        return i
      }
    }
  }
  return -1;

}




console.log(myLastIndexOf(['gee', 'gee', 'gee', 'gee', 'baby', 'baby'], 'gee'));
```

Comment: ah you're right!  Missed that I should be decrementing ... thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues there:

1. You're duplicating logic when you don't need to
2. You're returning on **first** match instead of **last** match
3. You're not declaring your variables, so your code is falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).
4. You're not returning -1 when you don't find a match

Here's an update with comments:

```js
function myLastIndexOf(array, searchValue, startIdx) {
  // If `startIdx` is undefined, use the end of the array
  if (startIdx === undefined) {
    startIdx = array.length - 1;
  }
  // Declare `i`
  var i;
  // Loop backward from `startIdx`
  for (i = startIdx; i >= 0; --i) {
    if (array[i] === searchValue) {
      // Stop the loop early
      break;
    }
  }
  return i; // Will be -1 if not found
}

console.log(myLastIndexOf(['gee', 'gee', 'gee', 'gee', 'baby', 'baby'], 'gee')); // => 3
console.log(myLastIndexOf(['gee', 'gee', 'gee', 'gee', 'baby', 'baby'], 'gee', 2)); // => 2, because of startIdx
```

The loop can actually be a bit shorter, but it's a bit less clear to a newbie:

```
// Loop backward from `startIdx`
while (i >= 0 && array[i] !== searchValue) {
    --i;
}
```

```js
function myLastIndexOf(array, searchValue, startIdx) {
  // If `startIdx` is undefined, use the end of the array
  if (startIdx === undefined) {
    startIdx = array.length - 1;
  }
  // Declare `i`
  var i = startIdx;
  // Loop backward from `startIdx`
  while (i >= 0 && array[i] !== searchValue) {
    --i;
  }
  return i; // Will be -1 if not found
}

console.log(myLastIndexOf(['gee', 'gee', 'gee', 'gee', 'baby', 'baby'], 'gee')); // => 3
console.log(myLastIndexOf(['gee', 'gee', 'gee', 'gee', 'baby', 'baby'], 'gee', 2)); // => 2, because of startIdx
```

Or using ES2015+ features:

```js
function myLastIndexOf(array, searchValue, startIdx = array.length - 1) {
  let i;
  for (i = startIdx; i >= 0; --i) {
    if (array[i] === searchValue) {
      // Stop the loop early
      break;
    }
  }
  return i; // Will be -1 if not found
}

console.log(myLastIndexOf(['gee', 'gee', 'gee', 'gee', 'baby', 'baby'], 'gee')); // => 3
console.log(myLastIndexOf(['gee', 'gee', 'gee', 'gee', 'baby', 'baby'], 'gee', 2)); // => 2, because of startIdx
```

Or with the shorter loop:

```js
function myLastIndexOf(array, searchValue, startIdx = array.length - 1) {
  let i = startIdx;
  while (i >= 0 && array[i] !== searchValue) {
    --i;
  }
  return i; // Will be -1 if not found
}

console.log(myLastIndexOf(['gee', 'gee', 'gee', 'gee', 'baby', 'baby'], 'gee')); // => 3
console.log(myLastIndexOf(['gee', 'gee', 'gee', 'gee', 'baby', 'baby'], 'gee', 2)); // => 2, because of startIdx
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning value on first match where as you should store index and return at end.

```js
function myLastIndexOf (array, searchValue, startIdx){
let index = -1;
if (startIdx !== undefined){
  for (i=startIdx; i>=0; i--){
    if (array[i] === searchValue){
      index = i
    }
  }
}

else if (startIdx === undefined){
  for (i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    if (array[i] === searchValue){
      index = i
    }
  }
}
 return index
}

console.log(myLastIndexOf(['gee', 'gee', 'gee', 'gee', 'baby', 'baby'], 'gee'))
```